# I get auto-logged-out in SharePoint when I access my tasks with Outlook. (and the other way around)

Tags: synchronisation, outlook

The problem occurs when I sync a task-list in SharePoint 2010 with Outlook 2007. Outlook asks for authentification, so use my Windows-domain username and password (that same as I use in SharePoint). Everthing works so far, the problem is that SharePoint logs me out at the same time. When I login into SharePoint, Oulooks logs me out and keeps asking for authentification the whole time (and so on)... This is kinda annoying (since Outlook is running the whole time), is there a way to use both, SharePoint and Outlook at the same time?

Note: this ONLY occurs when Outlook is synchronized to SharePoint (in some way).

Hope someone knows something, I keept searching for a possible solution for a few hours by now.

thanks in advance, Markus Schwalbe

Comment: are you joined to a domain? is sharepoint on the same domain? is the sharepoint host in your intranet zone in IE?

Comment: @djeeg I see what you are getting at. well SharePoint is in another domain, which shouldn't be a problem thought, because I'm using the form-based authentification method. Also, I forgot to mention that it's not running on our intranet but on the internet. (http://projekte.cbs.ag/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using forms based auth, you normally have a session cookie. Your browser has one session, and your outlook has another session. They cannot both be logged in at the same time. Previously I have solved this by using TMG. It does the forms auth on the proxy, and it uses a persistent cookie that can be shared across applications.

But you may be able to make the standard forms cookie persistent, either with web.config settings for using a custom auth provider.